# How to do the following operation in python in tricky way?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples as follows

```
[(1,4),(3,5),(2,9),(6,23),(3,21),(2,66),(5,20),(1,33),(3,55),(1,8)]
```

Now I need something like this

1. In the above list, each element is a tuple and the first item in a
   tuple is an index and the second item is a value.
2. We need to multiply all the tuple values whose indices are equal and then add all the multiplication result for all indices.
3. If there is only once tuple with certain index, we have to make the multiplication result zero for that. That means that tuple does
   not contribute to the final sum.

I would be so much obliged if some one can help me. I am new in python so finding it difficult.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way to do it. Use `itertools.groupby` to create groups corresponding to each index, multiply and add

```
from operator import itemgetter, mul
from itertools import groupby
z = [(1,4),(3,5),(2,9),(6,23),(3,21),(2,66),(5,20),(1,33),(3,55),(1,8)]
z = sorted(z, key=itemgetter(0))
z = groupby(z, key=itemgetter(0))
z = ((key, list(value for (key, value) in groups)) for (key, groups) in z)
z = ((key, reduce(mul, values, 1)) for (key, values) in z if len(values) > 1)
z = sum(value for (key, value) in z)
print z
7425
```

Comment: Showing the intermediate result has educational value. ;)

Comment: @MikeMüller, good point:-). However, intermediate printing prematurely exhausts the generator expressions that this solution is based on.

Comment: Of course. Starting from `groupby`, you would need to do all the steps again after printing.

Comment: Added a verbose version of this solution. It is work but is worth it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Transfer all the tuples into a dict where the keys are the first elements and the values are lists of the second elements. Filter the dict for values that have more than one element. Use `reduce()` to multiply the elements of each value together, and `sum()` to add all the products together.

Answer (score 0):

Another (slighlty different) way. We collect the elements into a dictionary where each `value` is a dictionary

```
import operator,collections
s=[(1,4),(3,5),(2,9),(6,23),(3,21),(2,66),(5,20),(1,33),(3,55),(1,8)]
s_d = collections.defaultdict(list)
for x in s: 
    s_d[x[0]].append(x[1])
```

s_d is now

```
>>> s_d
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {1: [4, 33, 8], 2: [9, 66], 3: [5, 21, 55], 5: [20], 6: [23]})
```

Now for each key, we multiply the values if length of values dictionary is more than 1 else return 0

```
>>>map(lambda y: reduce(operator.mul,y[1],0) if len(y[1])>1 else 0,s_d.items())
[1056, 594, 5775, 0, 0]
```

But you want the sum, so we sum it

```
>>>sum(map(lambda y: reduce(operator.mul,y[1],1) if len(y[1])>1 else 0,s_d.items()))
7425
```

Answer (score 0):

So everybody has already posted the solutions with the built in functions, but it is not that much extra to write a loop that goes through and does what you need!

```
>>> l = [(1,4),(3,5),(2,9),(6,23),(3,21),(2,66),(5,20),(1,33),(3,55),(1,8)]
>>> hold = []
>>> for i in range(min(l)[0],max(l)[0] + 1):
...     hold2 = []
...     mult = 1
...     for t in l:
...             if t[0] == i:
...                     hold2.append(t[1])
...                     mult *= t[1]
...     if len(hold2) > 1:
...             hold.append(mult)
... 
>>> sum(hold)
7425
```

you set one array for checking how many of each index there is and just iterate through the different indices and keep on multiplying by the next number with the matching index!

Also, this is going to be the fastest version you get. Just because it imports nothing and doesn't have to take the time to do that. Every version you were given is under a second, but I was bored so I timed them all:

```
Mine: 0:00:00.000477

1_CR: 00:00.073498

RedBaron: 0:00:00.079276
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is great but not easy to understand. Unfortunately, printing one of the `z` as readable list starting after `groupby` will consume the iterator as pointed out by 1_CR. Here is the solution again but with print outs of intermediate steps. Logically, all steps starting from `z3` need be re-done after every print.

```
from operator import itemgetter, mul
from itertools import groupby
from functools import reduce
import copy

z1 = [(1,4),(3,5),(2,9),(6,23),(3,21),(2,66),(5,20),(1,33),(3,55),(1,8)]
print('data:   ', z1)
z2 = sorted(z1, key=itemgetter(0))
print('sorted: ', z2)
z3 = groupby(z2, key=itemgetter(0))
print('grouped:', [(x, list(y)) for x,y  in z3])
z3 = groupby(z2, key=itemgetter(0))
z4 = ((key, list(value for (key, value) in groups)) for (key, groups) in z3)
print('lumped: ', list(z4))
z3 = groupby(z2, key=itemgetter(0))
z4 = ((key, list(value for (key, value) in groups)) for (key, groups) in z3)
z5 = ((key, reduce(mul, values, 1)) for (key, values) in z4 if len(values) > 1)
print('reduced:', list(z5))
z3 = groupby(z2, key=itemgetter(0))
z4 = ((key, list(value for (key, value) in groups)) for (key, groups) in z3)
z5 = ((key, reduce(mul, values, 1)) for (key, values) in z4 if len(values) > 1)
z6 = sum(value for (key, value) in z5)
print('sum:    ', z6)
```

And this is the reward for all this. I think this really helps to understand what is going on.
Functional programming can be fun, provided you understand what happens.

```
data:    [(1, 4), (3, 5), (2, 9), (6, 23), (3, 21), (2, 66), (5, 20), (1, 33), (3, 55), (1, 8)]
sorted:  [(1, 4), (1, 33), (1, 8), (2, 9), (2, 66), (3, 5), (3, 21), (3, 55), (5, 20), (6, 23)]
grouped: [(1, [(1, 4), (1, 33), (1, 8)]), (2, [(2, 9), (2, 66)]), (3, [(3, 5), (3, 21), (3, 55)]), (5, [(5, 20)]), (6, [(6, 23)])]
lumped:  [(1, [4, 33, 8]), (2, [9, 66]), (3, [5, 21, 55]), (5, [20]), (6, [23])]
reduced: [(1, 1056), (2, 594), (3, 5775)]
sum:     7425
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple procedural version:

```
tups=[(1,4),(3,5),(2,9),(6,23),(3,21),(2,66),(5,20),(1,33),(3,55),(1,8)]

di={}
for t in tups:
    di.setdefault(t[0],[]).append(t[1])

ans=0
for k in di:
    if len(di[k])==1: continue
    x=1
    for e in di[k]: x*=e
    ans+=x

print ans
```

prints 7425

If you want the *short* procedural version:

```
di={}
for t in tups:
    di.setdefault(t[0],[]).append(t[1])
print sum(reduce(lambda x,y: x*y,l) for l in di.values() if len(l)>1)
```

And here is a *tricky* version (from the wolf):

```
di={}
{di.setdefault(t[0],[]).append(t[1]) for t in tups}
print sum(reduce(lambda x,y: x*y,l) for l in di.values() if len(l)>1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer that uses dictionaries:

```
def calculate(t):
    t1 = {}    # first time we encounter an index
    t2 = {}    # product of values
    for index, value in t:
        if index in t1:    # we have seen this index already
            if index not in t2:    # start the multiplier
                t2[index] = t1[index]
            t2[index] *= value     # chain multiplication
        else:
            t1[index] = value      # first time for this index
    return sum(t2.values())    # sum of multipliers
```